# Toeplitz operators for other measures then Lebegue

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, operator-theory, toeplitz-operators

In the standard setting there is a lot known about Toeplitz operators i.e that the compression of a multiplication operator restricted to the Hardy space.

Are there any results when one has a arbitrary probability measure on the unit circle instead of Lebesgue? and furthermore when the dimension of the boundary is increased to say $n=2$. Results on multiplication operators seems to generalize to any finite measure.

If anyone has a good reference to what in known in this case let me know!